# pandas function, use previously computed value

Tags: pandas

Had a simple question that I have not found a simple answer to. As an example this data frame can be used:

```
A = pd.Series([0.1,-0.2,0.14,0.12,-0.11])
B = pd.Series([1.0,3.0,2.0,6.0,9.0])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'B':B})
```

I now would like to create a column C as follows:

```
C_i = A_i*(B_i+C_{i-1})
```

i.e. to compute the value of C I need the previously computed value of C. This can be done by a simple for loop, but I would like to use map, apply or some other pandas functionality. Can this be done i a simple manner?

I tested it in a spreadsheet and this what I am looking for:

```
A       B   C
0,1     1   0,10000
−0,2    3   −0,62000
0,14    2   0,19320
0,12    6   0,74318
−0,11   9   −1,07175
```

Comment: C(i=0) can take different values, but assume it is 10.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this:

```
df['C'] = df.A * df.B
df['C'] = df.C + (df.A * df.C.shift().fillna(0))
df
```

Which yields:

```
      A  B      C
0  0.10  1  0.100
1 -0.20  3 -0.620
2  0.14  2  0.196
3  0.12  6  0.754
4 -0.11  9 -1.069
```

Which looks like what you wanted.